# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: md2

Tags: java, gradle, bouncycastle, liferay-7

I am getting below error at runtime in my gradle project.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: md2
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.MD2$Mappings.configure(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.loadAlgorithms(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

gradle.properties

```
compile name: 'iPayPipe-1'
compile name: 'cryptix32-3.2.0'
compileInclude name: 'ibmjceprovider-1'

compile name: 'bcprov-ext-jdk15to18-164'
compileInclude name : "bouncycastle-1.20"
```

Comment: Please provide more context, what is it that you need help with here? For starters it would be useful to know what you're using to manage your external dependencies.

Comment: @NimbleNavigator I am using bouncycastle-1.20.